Stop JBoss 5 from writing log to /var/log/messages
I am managing a JBoss 5 legacy environment on Linux 8. To start / stop JBoss, I added a systemd service.
Everything that is logged to server/default/log/server.log is also being written to var/log/messages. What should be done to stop that?
My systemd service is:
[Unit]
Description=JBoss Application Server 
After=network.target terracotta.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17
User=jboss
Group=jboss
ExecStart=/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -c main1 -g MVRPartition  -b 0.0.0.0 -u 224.0.0.114 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 2> /dev/null
ExecStop=/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/shutdown.sh -S -s 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1
TimeoutStartSec=600
TimeoutStopSec=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


if you want to force this, you could set the permissions on /var/log/messages so the user running Jboss cannot write to that file

/var/log/messages has the default permission of 400 and jboss user is not in any privileged group. I don't think it is writing directly to this file but perhaps sends to syslog which writes to the file.
